# In Apache Hive. How to select a column that may not exist?

Tags: hive

I'm looking for a query that can automatically returns Null when one of the expression fails (e.g. on situations like a column this expression refers to does not exist), something like:

```
select id,IF (name) SUBSTR(name, 1, 2) ELSE NULL FROM table
```

which generates [id, name] when applied on table of

```
[id, name]
```

, and generates [id, NULL] when applied on table of

```
[id, creditcard]
```

Is it possible to do it in Hive?

Comment: can you explain more about the real reason you need something like this? specifying any column name that doesn't exist will lead to failure in hive (as like in all the other DBs i know).

Comment: Its a post-processing SQL append to the end of the result RDD in Spark SQL Hive Server to protect sensitive information. Since SQL has to be constructed from user's expressions, we can only let the invalid expression to fail smoothly